# During updating translation: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded

Tags: i18n-l10n

I've tried to install a second language to my Drupal7 site. It can be done either by automatically or manually translation. I tried both but I got into the following issue at halftime:

> Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded.

I tried to set higher values in php.ini:

```
default_socket_timeout = 240 (it was 60)
max_input_time = 360;
max_execution_time = 360;
```

I using local WAMP and Drupal7 installation. Port 8888.

I need help with configuration or another way to install it.

Comment: Temporarily setting `max_execution_time = 0;` will disable the 240 s limit and let you complete the task. But only in Drupal 7.40 and later, due to [issue #2233929](https://www.drupal.org/node/2233929).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open sites/all/modules/l10n_update/l10n_update.locale.inc; at line 28, change the code to the following one:

```
drupal_set_time_limit(840);
```

It will increase the execution time and will work. The original code set the time limit to 240.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you restarted your server (apache) to let the changes take effect.

Comment: It seems like the 10n_update.locale.inc setting overwrites the php init setting.